# file array giving different result for different browser

Tags: browser, cakephp-1.3

I am uploading a file in cake php.

```
<?php echo $form->create("Video",array('action'=>'add','name'=>'thisform','enctype'=>'multipart/formdata','onsubmit'=>'javascript: return validate();'));

echo $form->input("file_name",array('type'=>'file','id'=>'file_name','label'=>'','div'=>''));
echo $form->end();?>
```

In chrome I am getting the below

```
Array(

[Video] => Array(

       [file_name] => Array(

                [name] => imp.txt
                [type] => text/plain
                [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php63.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 1568
       )

 )
)
```

But in mozilla i am getting the below

```
Array(

[Video] => Array(

       [file_name] => 
    )
)
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend Ipsita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using
'enctype'=>'multipart/formdata' ;it was not working in mozilla.

But when I write
'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' and it works.

Comment: it's a silly mistake.But Chrome is not so strict like Mozilla.